# ¿Como puedo implementar este pseudocodigo en java?

Tags: java, algoritmos, recursión

Buen dia para todos espero que se encuentren muy bien.

Mi duda es la siguiente, estoy intentando implementar este pseudocodigo en lenguaje de programacion java:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero la verdad soy muy novato en temas de usar recursividad, eh intentado de muchas maneras pero la verdad no logro hacerlo de manera recursiva, por el momento he hecho esto:

```
public class MergeSort
```

{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int unsorted_array[]= {8,9,3,4,2,1};
    int sorted_array[]=new int [unsorted_array.length];

    int MergeSort (int unsorted_array[], int n,int left_sub_array,int right_sub_array[]) 
    {
        if(unsorted_array.length==1) 
            return unsorted_array[n];

        else {
            //split in two parts
            left_sub_array=unsorted_array[0]/unsorted_array[n/2];
            right_sub_array=unsorted_array[(unsorted_array.length/2)+1]=unsorted_array[unsorted_array.length];
             }
        return left_sub_array;

    }

    }
}
```

Añado que tengo que usar una función que lea los números por el usuario separados por coma y se que es de la siguiente manera :

```
String[] numeros=br.readLine().split(",");
int[] array = new int[numeros.length];

for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
array[i] = Integer.parseInt( numeros[i] );
}

for(int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
System.out.print(numeros[i]+" ");
}
```

pero como he dicho, no sabría donde poner esta función en un algoritmo recursivo.

Les agradecería mucho que me pudieran dar una ayuda, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Comprendo que algún compañero te responda con la respuesta completa, pero por mi parte no soy fan de resolver los ejercicios **didácticos** exponiendo la respuesta directamente, ya que el fin de esta tarea es que tú aprendas como se realiza la recursividad.

Lo que si te diré es que una función es recursiva porque se llama a sí misma. Dentro de tu método MergeSort deberías de volver a llamar a MergeSort, de hecho así se indica en el pseudocódigo en las lineas:

```
SortedL <- MergeSort(left-subarray) 
SortedR <- MergeSort(right-subarray)
```

También indicarte que el método MergeSort solo acepta un parámetro de entrada según el ejercicio y tu pusiste 3. Debería ser:

```
int MergeSort (int unsorted_array[])
```

Al final lo que estas haciendo es coger el array, dividirlo en dos partes e ir ordenando uno a uno los números llamando siempre a la misma función hasta, como se indica en el pseudocódigo, tu array solo quede con un numero (punto de parada de la recursividad). Una vez hecho esto los vuelves a unir con otra funcíon llamada Merge.

Y una última cosa, según como has puesto el código, estás metiendo MergeSort dentro de la funcion Main. El método debe quedar fuera de esta función. Te expongo un esquema básico:

```
public class EjercicioMerge
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int unsorted_array[]= leerArray();
        int sorted_array[]= mergeSort(unsorted_array);

        ...
    }

    static  int mergeSort (int unsorted_array[]) 
    {

        .....

    }

    static  int[] leerArray()
    {
        .....
    }

}
```